# WCF Service Not Encrypting Response

Tags: wcf, encryption, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-encryption

We have a WCF service hosted in IIS with the following **customBinding**. The service receives request from IBM Datapower that is encrypted and signed. The service can verify the signature and decrypt the request fine. **But the response sent out is not encrypted or signed.** (I can verify this using WCF logging)

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="myCustomBinding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="false" realm="" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myServiceBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="{serverCertificateName}" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" 
                            storeLocation ="LocalMachine" storeName ="My"/>
        <clientCertificate>
          <certificate findValue="{clientCertificateName}" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                        storeLocation ="LocalMachine" storeName ="My" />
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" includeWindowsGroups="false"/>
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors></behaviors>
```

The MessageContracts have ProtectionLevel set to `ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Check configuration of the IBM Datapower client if it can receive encrypted and signed responses.

Comment: @Pavel - Yes Datapower has been configured to receive encrypted and signed messages.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a WCF expert so forgive me if I am asking below question.

To encrypt and sign a content [in PKI domain] you need to have a private key [and everybody knows that is not included in certificate]. So I am just curious, as to where that private key is specified in above configuration. Is it the case that if you specify the certificate in above configuration, the corresponding private key is automatically picked up [I am just curious because I am not sure what is going under the hood]?

On the contrary when you receive an encrypted content, the only thing you need to verify and decrypt is the certificate [practically in most cases, keeping aside key negotiations that may happen].

Just let me know if this helps? May be this comment is too trivial [kindly excuse me if this is the case].

Comment: Yes the certificate has the private key to decrypt the content.